# Choice approaches for passing a selected feature to a method in ArcObjects? (C#)

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#, .net

It pains me to ask such a basic question, but after several hours (not exaggerating) of trying to figure this out and failing, I come to GIS.se

What I am trying to do is pass a selected feature and/or layer to a given method. In this example, it is to add a field to the selected layer in the ToC. The snippet calls for a feature class that is a member of the `IFeatureClass` interface (if my vocabulary is off, please correct me):

```
public void AddFieldToFeatureClass(IFeatureClass featureClass, IField field)
```

I create an `IField` easily enough:

```
IField statusField = new FieldClass();
```

But what is the preferred, cleanest, or most effective method to pass an `IFeatureClass` that is the currently selected layer in the TOC?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This works for me :

```
var fLayer = ArcMap.Document.CurrentContentsView.SelectedItem as IFeatureLayer;
if (fLayer != null)
    Debug.Print("got featurelayer");
else
    Debug.Print("no featurelayer selected (or maybe more than one is)");
```

Comment: I'm always being told that there is no Feature Layer selected... do I need to set up the `mxDocument` and `ActiveView` first?

Comment: When you look at the TOC in arcmap, is there a featurelayer selected?

Comment: The method I'm using actually calls for a feature class, so I changed it to `as IFeatureClass`. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: Yes, the SelectedItem will return a featurelayer - not a featureclass.  To get the featureclass use IFeatureLayer.Featureclass.

Comment: I finally got a handle on it. Thanks a lot-- your answer put me on the right path.